# Configure minTimeBetweenRequests for Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, infinispan

How can I actually set the value for `minTimeBetweenRequests`?

I can see from the source code here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/bcaab0e603b0f49923656059dbbcbc301d0ee1dd/model/infinispan/src/main/java/org/keycloak/keys/infinispan/InfinispanPublicKeyStorageProviderFactory.java#L74

that it's possible to configure a value for minTimeBetweenRequests to control how long it will wait between requests to an endpoint to retrieve public keys/configure oidc etc.

I cannot find any mention of it in the Keycloak docs, and my only clue is in https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/e7d2a32e9b9b2723da19b4920d84c243e8ef8c05/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/provider/ProviderFactory.java

which mentions a keycloak_server.json file. However, I cannot find anywhere in the docs which mentions that file or where to put it.

I have tried setting it by passing it into the cli as a flag:

```
resource "docker_container" "keycloak" {
  image = "keycloak-kms-storage-local"
  name  = local.container_name
  networks_advanced {
    name = var.network_name
  }
  command = [
    "start",
    "--db-url=jdbc:postgresql://${var.keycloak_db_host}:${var.keycloak_db_port}/${var.keycloak_db_database_name}?sslmode=disable",
    "--db-username=${var.keycloak_db_database_user}",
    "--db-password=${var.keycloak_db_database_password}",
    // Equivalent of start-dev; https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10956
    // but without requiring --auto-build which keeps boot time low.
    "--http-enabled=true",
    "--hostname=${local.container_name}",
    "--hostname-port=8080",
    "--hostname-strict=false",
    "--hostname-strict-https=false",
    "--minTimeBetweenRequests=0",
    "--log-level=DEBUG",
  ]
```

but in this case Keycloak won't even start because it does not recognise the config value. It also doesn't recognise it if I convert it to kebab case like the other config values.

```
JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values:    -Xms64m   -Xmx128m   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true   -javaagent:/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=*,includes=com.pkb.*:org.tolven.*:config.*   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:5005,server=y,suspend=n
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Unknown option: '--minTimeBetweenRequests=0'
Try 'kc.sh start --help' for more information on the available options.
```

Thanks!